# Spring Data ElasticSearch - Removed method reference in changelog / release notes?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm currently at `Spring Data ElasticSearch 3.0.6.RELEASE` and I'm looking at upgrading to `Spring Data ElasticSearch 4.X`

I see code references like `new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices()`.

I do not see such a method in 4.X. If this was removed, could someone please share a reference in the changelog / release notes. And any references to the alternatives please ?

Same with `ElasticsearchTemplate.query()` method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change with the index names was introduced in version 4.0. [See the changelog for this release.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-3.2-4.0.implicit-index-name).