# Spring Boot - Upgrading Elastic to 7.X from 5.X

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on a Spring Boot Application, version `2.0.1`
I use `Spring Data ElasticSearch 3.0.6.RELEASE` with `ElasticSearch 5.6`

I'm looking at using an `ElasticSearch 7` cluster. I'd like opinions on possible upgrade options and questions related to each

1. Is it possible to just upgrade `Spring Data ElasticSearch to 4.0.0.RELEASE` ?
2. Do I have to upgrade the entire Spring Boot Application to 2.3.X as per the compatibility matrix at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.requirements

I looked at changing `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` to `2.3.0` and had to add `spring-data-elasticsearch` with version `4.0.0.RELEASE`

But I started seeing compile errors due to missing methods / Interfaces as mentioned at
[Spring Data ElasticSearch - Removed method reference in changelog / release notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74194273/spring-data-elasticsearch-removed-method-reference-in-changelog-release-note)

Comment: 1. No, 2 Yes. You cannot (and shouldn't) upgrade just a part of the apps dependencies to a newer version, that will lead to all sorts of issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @M.Deinum. I hope this upgrade would not require me to make a lot of changes across other `spring-data` dependencies like JPA, Mongo etc. Is a JAVA version upgrade mandatory or I could continue with Java 8.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x still supports java 8. As of 3.0 the baseline is 17.